# When I compare an Object (type) does it uses the IEquatable of a specific class?

Tags: c#, generics, iequatable

My method receives two parameters, both of `Object` type. They have the same type, that implements `IEquatable`.

My question is: when I do: `param1 == param2` does the framework compare using the `IEquatable` operator override of specific class or does it uses the `object.Equals` that just compares the memory pointer of two objects?

Which is the best way to do this? Is with generics and derivation constraints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it does neither. The `==` operator by default will test for reference equality, regardless of the overridden behavior of your `Equals` method (if you've overridden it, which you certainly should have if you implemented `IEquatable<T>`).

That is to say, if your variables are typed as `object` but you want to use your own custom equality comparison, use `Equals(x, y)` rather than `x == y`.

Then, even if you've implemented `IEquatable<T>`, be sure to **still override `object.Equals`**, like this:

```
class MyType : IEquatable<MyType>
{
    public bool Equals(MyType other)
    {
        // Whatever you want.
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        // Presumably you check for null above.
        return Equals(other as MyType);
    }
}
```

While you certainly *can* also overload the `==` and `!=` operators for your type, this won't accomplish anything if you have references to objects of this type that are simply `object` variables, like this:

```
object x = new MyType();
object y = new MyType();
Console.WriteLine(Equals(x, y));
Console.WriteLine(x == y);
```

The above won't work as you might expect (if you've overloaded `==` and expect that to be used) because the `==` overload has to be resolved at compile-time; since `x` and `y` are typed as arbitrary objects, the C# compiler will pick the `object` type's `==` operator, which, again, just tests for reference equality.

---

**Update**: Now, you *can* ensure your `==` operator is used if your variables are typed as the class wherein you defined it *or* a more derived type. For example, given the following types:

```
class A
{
    public static bool operator ==(A x, A y) { return true; }
    public static bool operator !=(A x, A b) { return false; }
}

class B : A { }

class AComparer<T> where T : A
{
    public bool CompareEqual(T x, T y) { return x == y; }
}
```

The `AComparer<T>.CompareEqual` method above will use your overloaded `==` operator for *any* type `T` deriving from `A`.

The key thing to remember is that `==` is *static*, which means its overload resolution gets performed at compile-time, not at run-time using a vtable (unless you're using `dynamic`, but that's a whole other beast). So just be aware of that whenever you're using the `==` operator in code and you want the overload to resolve to that of your custom type.

Comment: And if use derivation constraints in my method. This change anything ? I can't overload the operator for object like equals ?

Comment: @Thiago: Sorry, I somehow missed your earlier comment. I *think* I understand what you are asking; give me a few minutes to update my answer.

Comment: @Thiago: Sorry, I totally forgot about that comment until now. See my update and let me know if it answers your question or not!

Answer (score 2):

You must override Equals too, and even GetHashCode(): have a look here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatable-t-you-still-must-override-object-s-equals-and-gethashcode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your method's parameters are specified as `object` then doing `param1 == param2` just performs reference equality, since the `==` operator isn't polymorphic.